# ADFS does not send X-Frame-Options header

Tags: http-headers, adfs, x-frame-options

ADFS Server does not send the `X-Frame-Options` header, although it is configured on the server.

```
(Get-AdfsResponseHeaders).ResponseHeaders

Key                       Value
---                       -----
X-Frame-Options           DENY
Strict-Transport-Security max-age = 31536000
X-Content-Type-Options    nosniff
X-XSS-Protection          1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy   default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:;
```

Accessing the `/adfs/ls` endpoint in the browser (F12 Developer Console), I see that all headers are sent except for the `X-Frame-Options`

[image]

I know that the `X-Frame-Options` are supposed to show because it gets displayed correctly on another ADFS Deployment.